# how to compute a percentage of the total number in a sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using MySQL 5.6 and have:

```
select network_id, count(*) from ad_sources where cpm is NULL group by network_id;
```

I'd like to add a value showing the count where cpm is NULL divided by the total number of ad_sources in that network multiplied by 100 such that the output would be like:

```
network_id count  percentage
  7        6       60%
```

assuming there are 10 ad_sources with a network_id = 7 (6 with cpm of NULL and 4 with cpm NOT NULL). How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to use average for this purpose:

```
select network_id,
       sum( cpm is NULL ) as num_null
       avg( cpm is NULL ) as null_ratio
from ad_sources
group by network_id;
```

This produces a ratio.  Multiply by 100 for a percentage.'